# Lua: Can't copy .png file

Tags: lua

I try to copy files by reading source file and write data to target - fail.
I try to use C extension like that:

```
    static int copy(lua_State *L)
{
    char ch;
    FILE *source, *target;
    const char * source_file = lua_tostring(L, 1);
    const char * target_file = lua_tostring(L, 2);
    source = fopen(source_file, "r");
    if( source == NULL )
    {
        lua_pushnumber(L, 1);
    }
    target = fopen(target_file, "w");
    if( target == NULL )
    {
        fclose(source);
        lua_pushnumber(L, 1);
    }
    while( ( ch = fgetc(source) ) != EOF )
        fputc(ch, target);
        fclose(source);
        fclose(target);
    return 1;
}
```

This code is working - i successfully copy text files, but when i try to copy .png image - i get fail again - in all of this methods i get breaked images.
I only can copy images by:

```
os.execute("cp file1 file2")
```

but it's very sloooow...

How to copy file without using os.execute?

Comment: Are you on Windows or a Unixoid?

Comment: Yes, i use Windows XP. I realy like unix, but now i need to write Windows app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the file in binary mode when reading/writing on Windows, otherwise there may be end-of-line and end-of-file processing that breaks the file. Add ["b" modifier](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-io.open).

Comment: He's using the C library, not the Lua one.

Comment: Right, but the "b" mode explanation is the same: "This string is exactly what is used in the standard C function fopen."; it was just faster to reference Lua manual ;)

Comment: I tried to open image with "r" mode and read icon line by line - fail. And i try to open image with "rb" mode and read data - fail. I get just "%PNG" file heder...

Comment: Is this a public image we can try this on?

Comment: Every image/file are broken. All examples just copy file header, and no copy data.

Answer (score 2):

There are various problems with your code. In order of appearance:

1. `ch` must be an `int`, otherwise one of the 256 valid characters might compare equal to `EOF`.
2. `lua_tostring` could return `NULL`. You should check for that or use `luaL_checkstring`.
3. As others have already said: Open both files in binary mode (`"rb"` and `"wb"`).
4. Make sure that you call `fclose`, `fgetc`, and `fputc` on non-`NULL` file handles only. There are probably some `return`s missing in there.
5. You don't check whether `EOF` signals the end of the file or an I/O error.
6. The return value (`1` in your case) tells Lua how many values from the Lua stack to pass back to the calling function. You return one value, but in some cases you don't push any values onto the Lua stack, and in other cases you push more than one.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, while on unixoids text-mode and binary-mode are identical, that happy state is not found on any Windows box.

Use binary mode unless you want your text-file translated!

---

Second issue, of course it is slow if you go character by character, as your multi-threading-enabled runtime must lock and unlock for each call.

Get some decent buffer, 2<sup>12</sup> bytes shoud be nice, and use `fread` / `fwrite`.